# How to flatten a Docker image?

Tags: docker

I made a Docker container which is fairly large. When I commit the container to create an image, the image is about 7.8 GB big. But when I `export` the container (not `save` the image!) to a tarball and re-import it, the image is only 3 GB big. Of course the history is lost, but this OK for me, since the image is "done" in my opinion and ready for deployment.

**How can I flatten an image/container without exporting it to the disk and importing it again? And: Is it a wise idea to do that or am I missing some important point?**

Comment: Do you build with the ```--rm``` option? This removes intermediate images. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: There are some other tricks to make the image smaller: call a bunch of install commands in one ```RUN```, remove unneeded ubuntu packages, _etc._ See https://github.com/dckc/ipython-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile for a good example.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Up from Docker 1.13, you can use the `--squash` flag.

---

Before version 1.13:

To my knowledge, you cannot using the Docker api. `docker export` and `docker import` are designed for this scenario, as you yourself already mention.

If you don't want to save to disk, you could probably pipe the outputstream of export into the input stream of import. I have not tested this, but try

```
docker export red_panda | docker import - exampleimagelocal:new
```

Comment: I just did this with "Docker version 1.1.1, build bd609d2" and the resulting image wasn't much smaller. It actually was a bit bigger. But the history was gone for the new image.

Comment: Works well with Docker 17.03.0-ce. From 33GB Image size was reduced to 19GB

Comment: `--squash` requires experimental flags for some daemons. `export` works on containers, not images. Do you have any suggestions on how to convert an image into a container without running anything inside that image? One idea I have is to run an entrypoint that doesn't exist in the container. That seems to still create a new container.

Comment: The metadata of the source image is not preserved across export+import. ([issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8334#issuecomment-57471427)). So you lose ENTRYPOINT, ENV, and CMD that way. Maybe `--squash` is the better way to flatten _and_ keep the metadata?

Comment: Where can you use the `--squash` flag?

Comment: docker build --squash -f <directory-to-dockerfile> .

Comment: This is still marked as experimental as of end of 2019.

Comment: So you can't use squash on an existing image. e.g. one that you have committed from a container.

Comment: A caution, `docker export CONTAINER` does not export the contents of mounted volumes.

Comment: When squashing, you lose the ability to share layers between images.

Answer (score 58):

Now that Docker has released the multi-stage builds in 17.05, you can reformat your build to look like this:

```
FROM buildimage as build
# your existing build steps here
FROM scratch
COPY --from=build / /
CMD ["/your/start/script"]
```

The result will be your build environment layers are cached on the build server, but only a flattened copy will exist in the resulting image that you tag and push.

---

Note, you would typically reformulate this to have a complex build environment and only copy over a few directories. Here's an example with Go to make a single binary image from source code and a single build command without installing Go on the host and compiling outside of docker:

```
$ cat Dockerfile 
ARG GOLANG_VER=1.8
FROM golang:${GOLANG_VER} as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN go-wrapper download 
RUN go-wrapper install

FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/app /app
CMD ["/app"]
```

The go file is a simple hello world:

```
$ cat hello.go 
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        fmt.Printf("Hello, world.\n")
}
```

The build creates both environments, the build environment and the scratch one, and then tags the scratch one:

```
$ docker build -t test-multi-hello .                                                                                                                              
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/9 : ARG GOLANG_VER=1.8
 ---> 
Step 2/9 : FROM golang:${GOLANG_VER} as builder
 ---> a0c61f0b0796
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /go/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> af5177aae437
Step 4/9 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 976490d44468
Step 5/9 : RUN go-wrapper download
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e31ac3ce83c3
Step 6/9 : RUN go-wrapper install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2630f482fe78
Step 7/9 : FROM scratch
 ---> 
Step 8/9 : COPY --from=builder /go/bin/app /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5645db256412
Step 9/9 : CMD /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8d428d6f7113
Successfully built 8d428d6f7113
Successfully tagged test-multi-hello:latest
```

Looking at the images, only the single binary is in the image being shipped, while the build environment is over 700MB:

```
$ docker images | grep 2630f482fe78
<none>                <none>              2630f482fe78        6 days ago          700MB

$ docker images | grep 8d428d6f7113
test-multi-hello      latest              8d428d6f7113        6 days ago          1.56MB
```

And yes, it runs:

```
$ docker run --rm test-multi-hello 
Hello, world.
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer by this time.. It's very effective and flexible!

Comment: note that with this approach the workdir, entrypoint, env, etc would be gone, you must repeat them. Apart of that, perfect! :)

Comment: Note that `COPY` rewrites all filesystem ownership to root (or the user running the command) which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [docker-squash](https://github.com/goldmann/docker-squash)

Install with:

```
pip install docker-squash
```

Then, if you have a image, you can squash all layers into 1 with

```
docker-squash -f <nr_layers_to_squash> -t new_image:tag existing_image:tag
```

A quick 1-liner that is useful for me to squash all layers:

```
docker-squash -f $(($(docker history $IMAGE_NAME | wc -l | xargs)-1)) -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:squashed $IMAGE_NAME
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!!!! No docker history!!!! :D Security First... Trust 0

Answer (score 2):

Build the image with the `--squash` flag:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#squash-an-images-layers---squash-experimental

Also consider mopping up unneeded files, such as the apt cache:

RUN `apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*`

Comment: What about existing images.