# docker container size much greater than actual size

Tags: linux, docker, debian

I am trying to build an image from `debian:latest`. After the build, the reported virtual size of the image from `docker images` command is 1.917 GB. I logged in to check the size (`du -sh /`)and it's 573 MB. I am pretty sure that this huge size is not possible normally. What is going on here? How to get the correct size of the image? More importantly when I push this repository the size is 1.9 GB and not 573 MB.

[image]

Output of `du -sh /*`

```
8.9M    /bin
4.0K    /boot
0   /dev
1.1M    /etc
4.0K    /home
30M /lib
4.0K    /lib64
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /opt
du: cannot access '/proc/11/task/11/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/11/task/11/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/11/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/11/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0   /proc
427M    /root
8.0K    /run
3.9M    /sbin
4.0K    /srv
0   /sys
8.0K    /tmp
88M /usr
15M /var
```

Answer (score 8):

Do you build that image via a *Dockerfile*? When you do that take care about your `RUN` statements. When you execute multiple `RUN` statements **for each of those a new image *layer* is created** which remains in the images history and counts on the images total size.

So for instance if one `RUN` statement downloads a huge archive file, a next one unpacks that archive, and a following one cleans up that archive the archive **and** its extracted files **remain in the images history**:

```
RUN curl <options> http://example.com/my/big/archive.tar.gz
RUN tar xvzf <options>
RUN <do whatever you need to do with the unpacked files>
RUN rm archive.tar.gz
```

There are more efficient ways in terms of image size to combine multiple steps in one `RUN` statement using the `&&` operator. Like:

```
RUN curl <options> http://example.com/my/big/archive.tar.gz \
    && tar xvzf <options> \
    && <do whatever you need to do with the unpacked files> \
    && rm archive.tar.gz
```

In that way you can clean up files and folders that you need for the build process but not in the resulting image and keep them out of the images history as well. That is a quite common pattern to keep image sizes small.

But of course you will not have a fine-grained image history which you could make reuse of, then.

**Update:**

As well as `RUN` statements `ADD` statements also create new image layers. Whatever you add to an image that way it **stays in history** and counts on the total image size. You **cannot temporarily `ADD` things** and then remove them so that they do not count on the total size.

Try to `ADD` as less as possible to the image. Especially when you work with large files. Are there other ways to temporary get those files within a `RUN` statement so that you can do a cleanup during the same `RUN` execution? E.g. `RUN git clone <your repo> && <do stuff> && rm -rf <clone dir>`?

A good practice would be to only `ADD` those things that are meant to stay on the image. Temporary things should be added and cleaned up with a single `RUN` statement instead where possible.

Comment: RUN statements can be combined, and yes it did reduce the size. But I have a ADD statement, a RUN statement to install and remove the installation file. How to combine these?

Comment: You cannot `ADD` an installation file and then remove it with a `RUN` statement. That would stay in the images history. If there is a way to do that with a `RUN` statement that would be the solution. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This actually helped me reducing the image size by over 50%.

Answer (score 4):

The 1.9GB size is not the image, it's the image *and its history*. Use `docker history textbox` to check what takes so much space.

See also [Why are Docker container images so large?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394243/why-are-docker-container-images-so-large)

To reduce the size, you can change the way you build the image (it will depends on what you do, see answers from the link above), use docker export (see [How to flatten a Docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713551/how-to-flatten-a-docker-image)) or use [other extensions](http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/08/19/squashing-docker-images/).

Comment: So what should I do for docker push <id> so that I only push the image (573MB)?

Comment: Might not be on topic for SO; perhaps Server Fault?

Comment: I updated my answer. @rholmes: I don't know, I see more questions on this issue (the image size) on SO than on Server Fault.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean...  SO has the quick turnaround and more eyes than any of the others, it seems.

Comment: SO or SF is fine for docker questions given how extensively docker is used by developers: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276579/should-docker-questions-go-on-stackoverflow-or-serverfault-or-superuser