# Analyzing docker image size

Tags: docker

Checking inside the docker for folder sizes:

```
bash-5.0# du -hs $(ls -d /*) | grep M
1.5M    /bin
1.2M    /etc
4.0M    /lib
168.5M  /root
636.9M  /usr
1.8M    /var
// about 900M
```

Checking on my computer for the size of the image:

```
% docker images
container-name           version              id        37 minutes ago      1.33GB
```

I'm wondering how can I attribute the missing 400M?

Comment: A docker image is made up multiple layers. If an intermediate layer contains data that a lower layer deletes, it will still have to be stored somewhere. `docker history` will show you all layers and their sizes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker container size much greater than actual size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627772/docker-container-size-much-greater-than-actual-size)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

docker history <image_name>
prints the size of each docker layer.

credit to Generous Badger comment.