# What is the difference between import and load in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I understand the difference between `export` (for containers) and `save` (for images). But at the end of the day the tarball produced by either save or export should be used as *an image*.

So why are there 2 commands to make an image from a tarball?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

[`docker save`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) will indeed produce a tarball, *but* with all parent layers, and all tags + versions.

[`docker export`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) does also produce a tarball, but without any layer/history.

It is often used when one wants to ["flatten" an image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22713551/6309), as illustrated in "[Flatten a Docker container or image](http://tuhrig.de/flatten-a-docker-container-or-image/)" from [Thomas Uhrig](http://tuhrig.de/about/):

```
docker export <CONTAINER ID> | docker import - some-image-name:latest
```

However, once those tarballs are produced, load/import are there to:

- [`docker import`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/) creates *one* image from *one* tarball which is *not even* an image (just a filesystem you want to import as an image)

  > Create an **empty filesystem image** and import the contents of the
  > tarball

  By itself, this imported image will not be able to be run from `docker run`, since it has no metadata associated with it (e.g. what the `CMD` to run is.)
- [`docker load`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) creates potentially *multiple* images from a tarred repository (since `docker save` can save *multiple* images in a tarball).

  > Loads a tarred repository from a file or the standard input stream

  By using `load` you can import the image(s) in the same way they were originally created with the metadata from the Dockerfile, so you can directly run them with `docker run`.

Comment: Is `docker image import` a synonym for `docker import`?

Comment: Probably (I am on my phone), considering the syntax docker image only came later.

Comment: Yes thats the exact difference. Just to add, as docker import or docker image import create a image from a filesystem, one can change / provide entrypoint, cmd, run etc. dockerfile instructions which option is not available with docker load or docker image load as this create 1/more images which already have it's layers & other history info preserved.

Comment: Can we save docker images as tars without the dependent  base layers?

I have nodejs image based on nodejs image, when i save my image the size turns out to be 800mb because of the nodejs base image layer. Is there any way to export the images without the base image

Comment: @NadirLaskar No: that is requested in https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8039. There is a workaround: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8039#issuecomment-480121360, but it might not apply to your specific use-case though.

Answer (score 32):

As a Docker-newbie, I learnt this difference the **hard way**.

- On one system:

  ```
  docker run -it myImage /bin/bash
  ```

  --> Works fine
- On that same system (using **save**):

  ```
  docker save myImage -o myImage.tar
  ```
- On second system (using **import**):

  ```
  docker import myImage.tar
  ```

  --> Works nicely, no issues, just tag required:

  ```
  docker tag _the_assigned_tag myImage
  ```
- On that second system:

  ```
  docker run -it myImage /bin/bash
  ```

  > **docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown**.

Looking for that error brought my to all kinds of reasons such as `MountFlags="slave"`, but the real reason turned out to be the one described in this post: I should have used load instead of import. Not knowing what was going on, Docker's error message didn't put me in any sense on track towards the "import" cause, till I stumbled over this post.

Answer (score 2):

*docker import* is mostly used with a tarball that is created out of running container. For Eg. *docker export containerID > /home/cntr.tar* then import this tarball to an image Eg. *docker import /home/cntr.tar mynewimage:tag*

Whereas *docker load* is used to load the image from a tarball that is created from another image. For Eg. *docker save  > /home/fromimg.tar* then load it back with *docker load < /home/fromimg.tar*

the main difference though docker save/load with image does preserve the image history. Whereas docker export/import with container flattens the image by removing all the history of the container.

Answer (score 2):

I want to share another difference from real world situation using `docker save` and on prod servers using `docker import` vs `docker load`.

On the server with internet access `docker import` worked the same way as `docker load`. Container was up and running without error and missing layers have been downloaded over internet.

On the server without internet - on-prem setup `docker import` cause above error on container start e.g.

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec:
> "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown.

In order to get saved container up and running without that we need to use `docker load < saved-container.tgz` In that way all the layers are imported.