# Docker save/load lose original image repository/name/tag

Tags: docker, docker-image

I'm using Docker 1.12.6.

I have pulled an image from the Docker registry.
I have exported the images as tar files using the `docker save` command.

I removed the original image and container and loaded the exported image using `docker load -i myImage.tar`.

Now, when running `docker images` I notice my image have lost its repository/tag information:

```
    REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              5fae4d4b9e02        8 weeks ago         581.3 MB
```

Why does it have this behavior and how do I keep the original image name?

Answer (score 51):

Use

```
docker save -o filename.tar <repo>:<tag>
```

The command `docker save <image id>` **removes** the repository and tag names.

To solve this, use `docker save <repo>:<tag>` it will keep the repository and tag name in the saved file. For example:

```
docker save -o ubutu-18.04.tar ubuntu:18.04
```

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem, so I used the following command to fix it manually:

`docker tag <Image-ID> <desired Name:Tag>`

<sub>[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#tag-an-image-referenced-by-name)</sub>

---

[**NOTE**]:

> It's inconsistent: `docker save image-repo-name` -> `docker load`
> restores name, `docker save SHA` -> `docker load` no names or tags,
> `docker save name:latest` -> `docker load` no names or tags.

**AND**:

> The current (and correct) behavior is as follows:
>
> ```
> docker save repo
> ```
>
> Saves all tagged images + parents in the repo, and creates a
> repositories file listing the tags
>
> ```
> docker save repo:tag
> ```
>
> Saves tagged image + parents in repo, and creates a repositories file
> listing the tag
>
> ```
> docker save imageid
> ```
>
> Saves image + parents, does not create repositories file. The save
> relates to the image only, and tags are left out by design and left as
> an exercise for the user to populate based on their own naming
> convention.
>
> <sub>[Reference](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3877)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This is a work around

1. Go to source docker host machine, create text file containing all the image details using the following command `docker image ls > images.txt`
2. The above command will produce a text file similar to the following
   `REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE <none>       <none>    293e4ed402ba   2 weeks ago    315MB <none>       <none>    d8e4b0afd6ba   2 weeks ago    551MB`
3. Make necessary edits to set the tag by using `docker image tag` command

`docker image tag 293e4ed402ba postgres:latest
docker image tag d8e4b0afd6ba wordpress:latest`

Answer (score 1):

A single image ID **can have multiple** names/tags,
so the way that you lose the names and tags is
what I would expect to happen after saving and loading the image to/from a tar ball.

Mode details are in the discussion about it [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3877)

Answer (score 1):

From docker documentation:

**cat exampleimage.tgz | docker import - exampleimagelocal:new**

```
root@mymachine:/tmp# cat myimage.tar | docker import --message "New image imported from tarball" - reponame:my-image-name
sha256:be0794427222dcb81182a59c4664b350ecb5ffb7b37928d52d72b31
root@mymachine:/tmp# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
reponame          my-image-name    be0794427222        6 seconds ago       4.31GB
```

This one worked for me.

Comment: Be careful with `docker import` it imports creates one image from one tarball which is not even an image (just a filesystem you want to import as an image)! There can be lots of side effects. For further info see the discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925261/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-load-in-docker

Answer (score 0):

```bash
function docker_image_export(){
  docker images | grep -v REPOSITORY | while read line
  do 
    # filename:
    # <repo>:<version>:<image_id>.tar , replace:
    # / --> +
    # : --> @
    # after replace: <repo>@<version>@<image_id>.tar
    local filename=$( echo $line | awk '{print $1":"$2":"$3".tar"}' | sed 's|:|@|g ; s|/|+|g' )
    image_id=$( echo $line | awk '{print $3}' )
    echo "docker save $image_id -o ${filename}"
    docker save $image_id -o ${filename}
  done
}

# For example:
# docker save 4f41f23e6002 -o mcr.microsoft.com+powershell@latest@4f41f23e6002.tar
# docker save 9c7a54a9a43c -o hello-world@latest@9c7a54a9a43c.tar
# docker save cc44224bfe20 -o nginx@alpine@cc44224bfe20.tar
# docker save f9e320b7e19c -o rancher+rancher@latest@f9e320b7e19c.tar



function docker_image_import(){
  ls *@*.tar | while read line
  do 
    # phase filename
    # delete .tar # mcr.microsoft.com+powershell@latest@4f41f23e6002.tar --> mcr.microsoft.com+powershell@latest@4f41f23e6002
    local filename=${line/.tar/}
    image_id=${filename##*@}
    # delete @4f41f23e6002 # mcr.microsoft.com+powershell@latest@4f41f23e6002 --> mcr.microsoft.com+powershell@latest
    filename=${filename/@$image_id/}
    local version=${filename##*@}
    # delete @latest # mcr.microsoft.com+powershell@latest --> mcr.microsoft.com+powershell
    local repo=${filename/@$version/}
    # replace + --> / # mcr.microsoft.com+powershell --> mcr.microsoft.com/powershell
    repo=$( echo ${repo} | sed 's|+|/|g' )
    echo "docker import ${line}"
    docker import ${line}
    docker tag ${image_id} "${repo}:${version}"
    echo "docker tag ${image_id} $repo:$version"
  done
}

# docker import hello-world@latest@9c7a54a9a43c.tar
# docker tag 9c7a54a9a43c hello-world:latest
# docker import mcr.microsoft.com+powershell@latest@4f41f23e6002.tar
# docker tag 4f41f23e6002 mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest
# docker import nginx@alpine@cc44224bfe20.tar
# docker tag cc44224bfe20 nginx:alpine
# docker import rancher+rancher@latest@f9e320b7e19c.tar
# docker tag f9e320b7e19c rancher/rancher:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

To automate this procedure, make sure you take a copy of the docker images output before:

```
docker images >images.txt
```

Then after you've loaded in all your images, do something like this:

```
cat images.txt | sed '1d' | awk '{print "docker tag "$3" "$1":"$2}' | /bin/bash
```

If you have images with  as tag, you need to edit images.txt first to skip these, and/or do them by hand.

Answer (score -2):

I wrote a one-line script that importing a bunch of .tar files and immediately tagging the image.

```
for image in $(ls); do docker tag "$(echo $(docker import  $image))" $image ; done
```

Note, that you should be inside the folder when all the tar files are located.

Comment: import is obviously not the way to do if you want to load a working image from Docker registry.

`docker import` strips almost all meta information, e.g. entry point, environment, labels, creator stamps, etc.

the only use case for import is when you're building a base layer and care only about filesystem contents