# How run docker images without connect to Internet?

Tags: windows, docker

I have installed `docker` in a system which has no connection to Internet so to run an image with `docker`, I had to download a simple image from [this](https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world) and from another system. Then I put this image in my offline system in this path : `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks`

but when I run `docker run hello-world` in cmd I see this message:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
```

and tries to download hello-world image form Internet but it has to no connection to the Internet so it field. Now I want to know where I should put my images in to be visible to docker?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine answers contains a lot of information. Probably you will need follow indications at https://forums.docker.com/t/where-are-images-stored/9794/11

Comment: do you see the image when you run docker images? If not, you need to create one using the docker build command.

Comment: no, first I download it from gidhub as a zip file but I do not how I can use it in another system which has not access to Internet. my goal is to put it in the destination path for images for docker when I execut `docker run {myImage}` @Ajjo

Comment: Hmm! I am not sure about making images from a tar or archive. Why don't you try making an image in a machine with internet access. And then use docker image save to create a tar, docker image load to load it and docker run? Please note that I haven't tried this myself. Just reference from the documentation.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can do it the easy way without messing around with folders, by exporting the docker image from any other machine with access to internet:

1. pull the image on a machine with internet access.

   ```
   $docker pull hello-world
   ```
2. save that image to a .tar file.

   ```
   $ docker save --output hello-world.tar {your image name or ID}
   ```
3. copy that file to any machine.
4. load the .tar file to docker.

   ```
   $docker load --input hello-world.tar
   ```

Check out:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_save/
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/#examples

Comment: when I execute `docker save --output hello-world.tar {your image name or ID}` , where the tar file will save? I want the path of it in windows? @Yasser

Comment: Run the command where you want to save it, the tar file is saved to the current working directory. 
Its docker command, so it behaves the same on the Linux or Windows.

Comment: Thank you! Now I am able to run any images in an offline system @Yasser

Comment: Thanks! Very useful.

Comment: Very nice indeed! Beware that using only image ID, the repository and tag name will be removed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957171/docker-save-load-lose-original-image-repository-name-tag

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to start a container using the dockerfile. You need to first build the image from dockerfile. You can do this via

> docker build -t < image name > < path >

You will require the internet connection while building the image.

You can check the image in your system using

> docker images

Once you build the docker image you can start the container without internet connection using

> docker run < image name >

Also you can export the same image using docker save and docker load functionalities.

Comment: this answer is irrelevant to the question asked

Comment: This IS relevant.  OP wants to run on a system without internet.  He doesn't specify he has to do it all on the offline system.  In fact, he got his original image from another system.  This solution is a valid alternative to the accepted answer above.

Answer (score -1):

Docker runs in a client-server architecture environment just almost like `git`. It can pull resources from the server online with the client on "your machine".

The command `$docker pull hello-world` requires connection to the server as part of docker itself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32108550)