# increase docker ram to install sentry server on linux

Tags: linux, docker, sentry

I am trying to install sentry docker on my linux .After clone it's repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise
```

I run this

```
$ ./install.sh
```

but i got this error:

```
alt@mx-alt:/mnt/Software/Linux/sentry/onpremise
$ ./install.sh 
Checking minimum requirements...
FAIL: Expected minimum RAM available to Docker to be 2400 MB but found  MB
```

this is my docker info:

```
$ sudo docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 19.03.13
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.19.0-12-amd64
 Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 15.63GiB
 Name: mx-alt
 ID: DRNU:OLX2:5VCT:GPNW:I3OV:4OHB:43UU:OVZL:OH5Y:5A2U:7MJA:SBHU
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

increase docker ram on linux?

Comment: Looks like the output of this line is empty for some reason: https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise/blob/19f4561a9e2abe32dc5eb5a03a332b50f2265b4b/install.sh#L99

Could you run that yourself and see what's going wrong?

Comment: Docker doesn't have a dedicated RAM pool on Linux (unlike, say, Docker Desktop for Mac, where the hidden Linux VM has a specific memory allocation).  A container can use all available system memory unless it's explicitly limited.  Can you show the application code you are trying to write that computes or uses this value?

Comment: I tried to install `sentry` on docker as i mentioned. but u can see https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise/blob/19f4561a9e2abe32dc5eb5a03a332b50f2265b4b/install.sh#L99 script @DavidMaze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write my answer maybe help to someone!

1 - I pull `busybox` first:

```
$ docker pull  busybox 
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
5f5dd3e95e9f: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:9f1c79411e054199210b4d489ae600a061595967adb643cd923f8515ad8123d2
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
docker.io/library/busybox:latest
alt@mx-alt:~


alt@mx-alt:~
$ sudo docker run --rm busybox free -m 2
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          16009        2176       11539         208        2293       13350
Swap:          8191           0        8191
alt@mx-alt:~
```

2-  ./install.sh

Done.

Comment: So you had an older version of busybox image that was not generating the expected output? If that's the case I'll need to add the pull step into the script, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. My server has restricted internet access, so I didn't have the latest busybox, which was causing the min spec issue. I downloaded the images into a different server and [exported them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125169/how-run-docker-images-without-connect-to-internet) into my server to get it working.