# docker container with a local docker image

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am a newbie and I supposed to create a docker container with an image that my friend pass me using a usb drive. I get the procedure to how to create the container after the image is uploaded on my docker (i.e when I can see it with the command `docker image ls`) but I do not know how to upload this image which is on a usb stick to my docker.

Comment: What format is it in? `.tar`?

Comment: yes it is .tar image

Comment: Look into `docker import` then

Comment: ohh yes I just get to upload my image with that, thanks a lot @sneep

Comment: Perhaps `docker load` might be better. See e.g. here for differences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925261/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-load-in-docker

Comment: Actually docker load worked better for me (i dnt understand the details too much), but when i use the image I upload with docker import to create a container I was getting errors, on the other hand the image I upload with docker load worked smooth to create a container.

Answer (score 1):

it's simple as `docker load < imageFile.tar`