# Can`t run docker gitlab container after import

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have exported `gitlab` container and send it to another server as `gitlab.tar` file.

imported container with:

`docker import gitlab.tar gitlab`

`docker images` says:

```
gitlab              latest              432365b4f2fd        9 minutes ago       1.56GB
```

but when try to run image I got:

`docker run -d 432365b4f2fd`:

`docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.`

also I tried `docker run -d gitlab:latest`

Comment: You are specifying a command to run when invoking the container.

Comment: Not that it should matter, but did you try `docker run -d gitlab:latest`

Comment: Yes I tried, I got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `export` clears the history of the image so you docker container currently doesn't remember how it suppose to run. You have two solutions:

- Check [gitlab's dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/dockerfile/) and use the command that is being used like below (I am not sure how much this solution would be efficient but it worked for me before with another image)

  ```
  docker run -d gitlab:latest /usr/local/bin/wrapper
  ```
- Use `docker save` to save a tar file then use `docker load` to restore it on the new server.

  ```
  # To save an image
  docker save -o gitlab-latest.tar gitlab:latest
  # To load an image
  docker load --input gitlab-latest.tar
  ```

  [For more docker save usage](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/)

Also you may check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36932570/2336650) for more details