# starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown

Tags: docker

I have a docker image and container on machine A.  But I really want them on machine B.
I saved the image from A

```
docker save <hash> > image.tar
```

and then scp'd and loaded it on the target machine B:

```
docker import image.tar
```

I attempted to start the container (there is no entrypoint) with a shell:

```
docker run  -it dbc2ffe8167e /bin/bash
```

And I get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

On machine A I verified the container runs using the exact same command (different hash of course) and I checked that the output of 'docker inspect' was identical.

I extracted the image and made sure that the /bin/bash file was binary compatible with machine B's OS and it is (It doesn't run independently due to libraries differences) but the binary itself appears to be fine.

Any further suggestions on what the cause could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
docker load --input image.tar
```

instead of

```
docker import image.tar
```

---

also see:
[What is the difference between import and load in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925261/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-load-in-docker)

Comment: Huh. That definitely made a difference. Thanks!