# Create a docker image from a running container

Tags: docker

I want to create a docker image with a few customizations. I have an existing image of 16GB  and I have launched it as a container. Now I have deleted all the unnecessary files from the container and committed it as a new image. But the new image is still showing 16GB. Actually the new image should have only ~1GB in size.

How can I create a new small size image from a running container?
Steps followed:

```
1) launched a container from the 16GB image
2) deleted unwanted files from the container
3) committed new image from the container
```

Thanks
sarath

Comment: Have you tried this https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Comment: you can export that using docker export or docker commit

Comment: You can't just delete files from a large image to make it smaller. You can delete them, of course, and the filesystem will show that they aren't there *in the running container*, but they will still be there in the earlier layers where they were added. Have a read of [Dockerfile best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to reduce the size of the existing image, export it using [`docker export`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) and then import it using [`docker import`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22713551/8482479) question might also help.