# Importing R CRAN, Bioconductor and github R packages in one Dockerfile

Tags: r, docker

My apologies because I think this may be a simple question but it is something that I am really struggling to understand!

As a background, I am trying to create a `Dockerfile` which installs a lot of `R CRAN` and `R Bioconductor` packages as well as some R packages from  `Github`. I want to do this as quickly as possible so I'm using `rocker`'s base image to install binary files, see here for a great, quick tutorial: https://datawookie.dev/blog/2019/01/docker-images-for-r-r-base-versus-r-apt/

My approach is first to install all my necessary packages as binaries and, if any are not available install them from source. After this, I use the `Bioconductor` base image to install the necessary `Bioconductor` packages.

However, the packages I installed through the `rocker` base image aren't available after I import the  `Bioconductor` base image. This is where I feel I don't have a clear understanding of creating Dockerfiles but I can't seem to find an answer in any documentation. Is there some way to copy these over after importing another image? I didn't know if this is necessary, I have seen others do it the same way, such as the question poster here: [Minimizing the size of docker image R shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908358/minimizing-the-size-of-docker-image-r-shiny-app)

To note, I import the `Bioconductor` base image as I thought this would help deal with dependency issues. I guess I could just install the `Bioconductor` packages like the R packages that weren't available as binaries but I want to do this as quickly and cleanly as possible and I thought that this would slow things down.

Essentially, I want to know what's the quickest way to install, R binaries, R non-binaries, R bioconductor and github packages all in one dockerfile.

An example of my approach is below with a very small subset of the packages I need. Note, I have shown my full approach to install R binaries, R non-binaries, R bioconductor and github packages but for the issue I am having see what happens to the `tidyverse` R package before and after I import the `Bioconductor` image; the call `library(tidyverse)` runs before but fails after:

Dockerfile

```
## Use r-ubuntu, prev r-apt:bionic to enable the use of binary r packages for speed for R 4.0
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu:18.04

## Install available binaries - for speed
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -qq \
r-cran-tidyverse \
r-cran-ids \
r-cran-snow

## Install remaining packages from source
COPY ./requirements-src.R .
RUN Rscript requirements-src.R

## This works
RUN R -e 'library(tidyverse)'

## Install Bioconductor packages
# Docker inheritance
FROM bioconductor/bioconductor_docker:RELEASE_3_12
COPY ./requirements-bioc.R .
#Don't bother running for speed but this will run
#RUN R -e 'BiocManager::install(ask = F)' && Rscript requirements-bioc.R

#This will fail - can't find the package
RUN R -e 'library(tidyverse)'

## Install from GH the following
#Don't bother running for speed but this will run
#RUN installGithub.r mojaveazure/loomR 


EXPOSE 8787

## Make R the default
CMD [”R”]
```

requirements-src.R

```
pkgs <- c(
'spelling',
'english',
'DT'
)

install.packages(pkgs)
```

requirements-bioc.R

```
bioc_pkgs<-c(
'biomaRt',
'DropletUtils',
'rhdf5'
)

BiocManager::install(bioc_pkgs,ask=F)
```

Comment: While I agree that one shouldn't waste time, is there a reason you really need to reduce the image-creation time? Unless you're doing it daily, I would expect that getting it to work well and consistently would win out over trying to be frugal on package compilation time.

Comment: Side question, though, are the library paths in the first (`rocker`) container masked by directories in the second (`Bioconductor`)?

Comment: Image creation time is a problem as the previous image was taking hours to build and docker hub has a 2 hour build limit so it had to be build manually each time (the real use case has a lot of packages to install) - this is what I want to avoid! On the side question, I actually don't know.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now (I don't build on docker hub so have never run into a build-time limit). For the second, try explicitly creating a package library directory elsewhere, install into *it*, then see if it is still available after you overlay the Bioconductor base image.

Comment: This is where my lack of an extensive knowledge on Docker gets in the way, I understand that approach in principle and why it should work but I haven't done something like that before. You may not know but would that approach still be useable with a github action to build the docker on push?

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in the interest of anyone else who is facing a similar problem, I will post my solution. I am not suggesting that this is the only solution so if others find better alternatives, I'll update to it.

In the end my approach to creating docker image which installs a lot of R CRAN and R Bioconductor packages as well as some R packages from Github was:

1. **Use the latest [Rocker RStudio image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio)** - to get packages installed as binary and to also enable easy debugging of your package with the correct dependencies since you can interactively run your image
2. **Install all libraries from the latest [Bioconductor image](https://www.bioconductor.org/help/docker/)** - to ensure you can install any Bioconductor package without issue
3. **Install CRAN binaries**
4. **Install CRAN packages from source** - where binaries aren't available
5. **Install Bioconductor packages**
6. **Install Github packages**

My solution uses this steps in this order and should prove as a fast and efficient solution (the use case for me was an R package which required >80 other packages from CRAN, Bioconductor and Github as dependencies! This solution reduced the runtime to a fraction of the original). Also, since we are using the latest version of Rocker RStudio and packages, this should stay up-to-date with the latest versions of software and packages.

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
#LABEL maintainer="John Doe"

## Use rstudio installs binaries from RStudio's RSPM service by default,
## Uses the latest stable ubuntu, R and Bioconductor versions
FROM rocker/rstudio


## Add packages dependencies - from Bioconductor
RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ## Basic deps
        gdb \
        libxml2-dev \
        python3-pip \
        libz-dev \
        liblzma-dev \
        libbz2-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libgit2-dev \
        ## sys deps from bioc_full
        pkg-config \
        fortran77-compiler \
        byacc \
        automake \
        curl \
        ## This section installs libraries
        libpcre2-dev \
        libnetcdf-dev \
        libhdf5-serial-dev \
        libfftw3-dev \
        libopenbabel-dev \
        libopenmpi-dev \
        libxt-dev \
        libudunits2-dev \
        libgeos-dev \
        libproj-dev \
        libcairo2-dev \
        libtiff5-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libgsl0-dev \
        libgslcblas0 \
        libgtk2.0-dev \
        libgl1-mesa-dev \
        libglu1-mesa-dev \
        libgmp3-dev \
        libhdf5-dev \
        libncurses-dev \
        libbz2-dev \
        libxpm-dev \
        liblapack-dev \
        libv8-dev \
        libgtkmm-2.4-dev \
        libmpfr-dev \
        libmodule-build-perl \
        libapparmor-dev \
        libprotoc-dev \
        librdf0-dev \
        libmagick++-dev \
        libsasl2-dev \
        libpoppler-cpp-dev \
        libprotobuf-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libperl-dev \
        ## software - perl extensions and modules
        libarchive-extract-perl \
        libfile-copy-recursive-perl \
        libcgi-pm-perl \
        libdbi-perl \
        libdbd-mysql-perl \
        libxml-simple-perl \
        libmysqlclient-dev \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        libgdal-dev \
        ## new libs
        libglpk-dev \
        ## Databases and other software
        sqlite \
        openmpi-bin \
        mpi-default-bin \
        openmpi-common \
        openmpi-doc \
        tcl8.6-dev \
        tk-dev \
        default-jdk \
        imagemagick \
        tabix \
        ggobi \
        graphviz \
        protobuf-compiler \
        jags \
        ## Additional resources
        xfonts-100dpi \
        xfonts-75dpi \
        biber \
        libsbml5-dev \
        && apt-get clean \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#install R CRAN binary packages
RUN install2.r -e \
testthat

## Install remaining packages from source
COPY ./requirements-src.R .
RUN Rscript requirements-src.R

## Install Bioconductor packages
COPY ./requirements-bioc.R .
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
   libfftw3-dev \
   gcc && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN Rscript -e 'requireNamespace("BiocManager"); BiocManager::install(ask=F);' \
&& Rscript requirements-bioc.R

## Install from GH the following
RUN installGithub.r theislab/kBET \
chris-mcginnis-ucsf/DoubletFinder \
```

Note that the CRAN packages from source and the Bioconductor packages are held in separate scripts in the same folder as your Dockerfile.

requirements-src.R:

```
pkgs <- c(
'spelling',
'english',
'Seurat')

install.packages(pkgs)
```

requirements-bioc.R:

```
bioc_pkgs<-c(
'biomaRt',
'SingleCellExperiment',
'SummarizedExperiment')

requireNamespace("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(bioc_pkgs,ask=F)
```